# Downloaded tar file is not opening in node js.?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to download the tar file using node js , file is saving but not able to open that file I have tried the following code

```
var fs = require("fs");
var fn = "version1.tgz";
var request = require('request');
var downloadUrl = "https://url/api/download?downloadFile="+fn+"&username=mkhun";
request({
    url: downloadUrl,
    method: 'POST',
}, function (err, resp, body) {
    var rmv = body;
    console.log(rmv);
    fs.writeFile(fn,rmv,function(err,data){
            console.log(err);
    });
});
```

but the same thing is working with javascript ajax

```
var fn = "version1.tgz";
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var downloadUrl = "https://url/api/download?downloadFile="+fn+"&username=mkhun";
console.log(downloadUrl);
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var blob = this.response;
     var fileName = fn;
     var link=document.createElement('a');
     link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
     link.download=fileName;
     link.click();

} else if(this.readyState == 2) {
        xhttp.responseType = "blob";
    }
};
xhttp.open("POST", downloadUrl , true);
xhttp.send();
```

I don't know how to fix the issue in node-red

Comment: log the `err` of the `request` callback and  post any log errors please so we can help out

Comment: I am getting `null` for both request callback and the file write call back. If I make the log of `body` I am getting like the following strings ` ��\ ��G�`.

Comment: This is an issue of encoding when receiving `request` data. Try using steams to pipe the data into file directly from a Buffer. Try `encoding: null` in the `request` options maybe it would work.

Comment: @Bamieh  Thanks This is working as expected. you can make this as an answer.

Comment: alright. glad it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue of encoding when receiving request data.

You can use `streams` to `pipe` the request into the filesystem directly from a Buffer. Otherwise, you can use `encoding: null` in the `request` options

```
request({
    url: downloadUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    encoding: null
}, ...)
```